duda while ingresa en python
Buenos días tengo una duda, cuando ejecuto el código me ingresa el valor de salida que sería el número negativo ej. [10, 20, 30 ,40, -1] lo ingresa y ahí sale del bucle, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo evitar eso?
desde ya muchas gracias
numeros = []
while True:
    print("Escribe un número Entero...")
    numero = int(input("Ingrese un número: "))
    numeros.append(numero)
    if numero < 0:
        print("Has salido del búcle.")
        break
    print(numeros)


Tu problema pasa porque estas recibiendo el número negativo y lo agregas a lista y luego de eso frenas el bucle. Solo tienes que mover de lugar el append (al final) para agregar solo elementos positivos
numeros = [] 
while True: 
    print("Escribe un número Entero...")  
    numero = int(input("Ingrese un número: "))
    if numero < 0: 
       print("Has salido del búcle.") 
       break 

    numeros.append(numero) # lo dejamos al final
print(numeros)

Otra manera sería asignar el valor directamente en el while y condicionarlos solo a positivos
numeros = [] 
while (numero := int(input("Ingrese un número: "))) >= 0: 
    numeros.append(numero)     
print(numeros)


Para quien lo pueda necesitar: ¿Qué significa := en Python?

muchas gracias! lo solucione de esta forma tambien
numeros = []
while True:
   print("Escribe un número Entero...")    
   numero = int(input("Ingrese un número: "))
   numeros.append(numero)   
   if numero < 0:
    print("Has salido del búcle.")
    numeros.pop()
    break
print(numeros) 

